# Create dynamic javascript classes, to extend dto class for swagger

Tags: javascript, swagger, nestjs, nestjs-swagger

I am trying to create **my own "Mapped types", for the swagger dto in nestJS**.

In the [official document](https://docs.nestjs.com/openapi/mapped-types) there are many "Mapped types". But, I need to add all the fields of a class, and make ONLY SOME as optional.

For which, I do something like this:

```
export default class CreateUserDto extends IntersectionType(
  OmitType(UserDto, ['nickname'] as const),
  PartialType(PickType(UserDto, ['nickname'] as const)),
) {}
```

This works perfectly. All fields are added, but only nickname as optional.

But, it is not very practical to reuse. So I would like to **create a custom class** to be able to extend it and have the same result.

I try the following:

```
const OptionalType = (dto, optional) => {
  return class NewClass extends IntersectionType(
    OmitType(dto, optional as const),
    PartialType(PickType(dto, optional as const)),
  ) {};
};

export default class CreateUserDto extends OptionalType(UserDto, [
  'nickname',
]) {}
```

And directly returning "IntersectionType" without creating a class.

But this didn't work.

When I try to use the "optional" variable I get the error...
["A 'const' assertions can only be applied to references to enum members, or string, number, boolean, array, or object literals."](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ZO63.png)

**Could you guide me on how to achieve what I want? please**

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add the `as const` to the `optional` inside the `OptionalType`, you'd only need to add it to when you invoke `OptionalType`.

e.g.

```js
const OptionalType = (dto, optional) => {
  return class NewClass extends IntersectionType(
    OmitType(dto, optional),
    PartialType(PickType(dto, optional)),
  ) {};
};

export default class CreateUserDto extends OptionalType(UserDto, [
  'nickname',
] as const) {}
```

Comment: The swagger in nestJS is not generating the output I need, but, your answer solves the original problem in my post, thank you very much!